# basic page within a basic page

Tags: routes, 7

Is there any way to create a basic page within a basic page?
For example, when you create new content, you have the option of making a top menu.
Within that basic page you have just created, can you also make another basic page with a top menu within that basic page?

Sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess that you are asking about creating hierarchical menu structure, so that menu item pointing to your "another basic page" is a child of menu item for first "basic page"?

Then yes, there is a way, and pretty easy to it, when creating a second "basic page" and providing a menu link for it (in `Menu settings` section), make sure that you select your first "basic page" in `Parent item` dropdown.